# Confusion in Spring Security Filter Chain

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have just started to look into Spring security. I am reading Spring Security reference guide. Here it is written as

> Using filters="none" operates by creating an empty filter chain in
>   Spring Security's FilterChainProxy, whereas the access attributes are
>   used to configure the FilterSecurityInterceptor in the single filter
>   chain which is created by the namespace configuration. The two are
>   applied independently, so if you have an access contraint for a
>   sub-pattern of a pattern which has a filters="none" attribute, the
>   access constraint will be ignored, even if it is listed first. It
>   isn't possible to apply a filters="none" attribute to the pattern /**
>   since this is used by the namespace filter chain. In version 3.1
>   things are more flexible. You can define multiple filter chains and
>   the filters attribute is no longer supported.

Can someone elaborate on this note from reference documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to spring 3.1 suppose yopu want to allow access to a particular url/pattern i.e. you dont want spring security to be applied on it, you can add

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/nonsecure/**" filters="none" />
```

Here filters =none create s an empty security filter chain and hence this resource is not secured by spring security.

Even if you add access attribute along with filters="none", it will  be igonred.

for spring 3.1 and above you can define multiple filter chains like

```
<security:http pattern="/nonsecure/**" security="none"/>

 <security:http pattern="/secure/**" >
....other security config
</security:http>
```